# Creating a scatterplot by category with lines connecting values from the same IDs in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a scatter plot based on two categories and connect any dots that have the same ID's by a line. I've created a sample data set. I'd like days to be the x-axis, score to be the y-axis and to have a different color for each of the values study's. I can do that in ggplot as I've shown, but I can't figure out how to connect the dots that come from the same ID.

```
library(ggplot2)
Id <- c(1,2,3,4,1,3)
Score <- c(24,27,17,25,28,24)
Study <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
days <- c(8,17,42,36,69,80)

X <- as.data.frame(cbind(Id, Score, Study, days ))

ggplot(X, aes(days, Score)) + 
geom_jitter(width = 0.3, height = 0.3, aes(colour = as.factor(Study))) +
geom_segment(aes(x=42, y=17, xend=80, yend=24), lty=2, colour="purple") +
geom_segment(aes(x=8, y=24, xend=69, yend=28), lty=2, colour="purple")
```

[image]

For example I'd like there to be a line between ID 1's value of 24 and 28 and also from ID 3's value of 17 to 24. I've added these with geom_segment, but in the actual data set I'm working with their will be hundred of connections. I appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Nice reproducible example, clear problem statement, and attempted solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `group` aesthetic:

```
ggplot(X, aes(days, Score)) +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.3, height = 0.3, aes(colour = as.factor(Study))) +
    geom_line(aes(group = Id), lty = 2, colour = "purple")
```

from `?geom_line`'s description:

> The `group` aesthetic determines which cases are connected together.